# How do I create a large amount of ellipses or rectangles in XAML without declaring every single one?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am creating a user-editable app UI in UWP. I have all of the properties of the ellipses/rectangles initialized in my C# code that is received from the user so that is not an issue. I would prefer to not have 1,000+ declarations of ellipses and rectangles in my XAML code however when I try to declare ellipses or rectangles in my C# code it isn't drawn. Is there any way to create a array, list, collection, etc. of those objects in the XAML code or am I missing something in C#?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please tell me how do you want to place these ellipses?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Ellipses}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And create this Property in your ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<Ellipse> Ellipses { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Ellipse>
{
    new Ellipse{Width = 30, Height = 30, Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red},
    new Ellipse{Width = 30, Height = 30, Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green},
};
```

And the result is:
[image]